# Apache CXF and redundant namespaces in the request

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am using Apache CXF generated SOAP WebService client. The problem, however, is with the many redundant namespaces added to each request, instead of just one namespace for the called WS method.

The example request coming out:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns10:getSomeData
            xmlns="http://example.com/schemas/different_data"
            xmlns:ns10="http://example.com/schemas/some_data",
            xmlns:ns11="http://example.com/schemas/some_other_data"
            xmlns:ns12="http://example.com/schemas/another_data"
            xmlns:ns13="http://example.com/schemas/and_so_on"/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Whereas the completely sufficient request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns10:getSomeData
        xmlns:ns10="http://example.com/schemas/some_data"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It looks like the request contains every possible namespace that could appear in the response. Is it possible to configure the Apache CXF (or anything it uses underneath) to skip the redundant namespaces?